# How to secure cpanel?

Tags: attacks

Most of us save our cpanel passwords on the browser because we log in often. If someone stole the data of the browser they will have our website .

If they log in with the password from a different location, will they be allowed to control our website ? Can't we protect cpanel based on the location of the IP address?

Or is there any other way to secure cpanel?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to secure cPanel and WHM. If you can control over the server you can enable to PINs under the security tab. If you have ConfigServer Security & Firewall installed you can limit the logins based on ip address, country or count. If you are a cPanel *user*, just don't save passwords in the browser. Use a password manager with a generated password for your cPanel account.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should not save the password based on the browser. Secondly, you can enable [two way authentication](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/68Docs/Two-Factor+Authentication+for+cPanel) in cpanel. So that even if someone stole the password s/he still need to have to security PIN to enter. Lastly, you should use the password manager such as [lastpass](https://www.lastpass.com/) or [keepass](https://keepass.info/).